# What book about algebraic combinatorics is it?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algebraic-combinatorics

Recently I found [a fragment of a book](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~jobal/teach/nullstellensatz.pdf) about algebraic combinatorics on the internet coincidentally. And I found it's really an excellent resource of learning polynomial method, about Combinatorial Nullstellensatz, Cauchy-Davenport Theorem, or Chevalley-Warning Theorem and so on. But I have no idea about what the original book is. It is from the home page of Jozsef Balogh. I have no idea whether it was written by him and whether it was published. I have searched on Google book but no result.

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of Dr. Balogh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be *The Art of Combinatorics, Volume IV: Arrangements and Methods* by Douglas B. West; see here: http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/.

“Four advanced graduate textbooks and research references on classical and modern combinatorics. Preliminary versions available by special arrangement for use in specialized graduate courses; not available for individuals.”

Comment: Does anybody know a place where one can by this book (indeed the 4 volumes)? I am unable to find any information on the web (isbn, etc)

Comment: @boumol: As I interpret it, they are a work in progress (and hence not published yet).

Comment: These 4 books (and the same for the other one with the title "Combinatorial Mathematics") seem (just looking at the previous fragment and at the available table of contents) so terrific at the current version, that I would like to encourage Douglas West to make it now available in whatever format he decides (online current draft, publsihed book, etc). If anybody is in contact with him, please send the message.